# An easy way to switch styles between multiple elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code to get data from NASA.api and create gallery from the data received from the sever.

```js
let source, load,gallery;
let grid = document.querySelector('#grid')

function send(num) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let link = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=" + num
  xhr.open('GET', link, true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      source = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none'
      create()
      if (gallery) gallery.forEach(item => item.style.opacity = 1)
    }
  }
}

function create() {

  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    let copyright = source[i].copyright
    if (!copyright) copyright = '<i>Unknown</i>'
    let content = source[i].explanation.split(' ').slice(0,20).join(' ')

    grid.innerHTML += `
       <div class='gallery'>
        <div class='pho'>
         <img src=${source[i].url}>
         </div>
         <div class='allcontent'>
         <div class='title'>${source[i].title}</div>
         <hr class='hr'>
         <div class='date'>Date: ${source[i].date}</div>
          <div class='copyright'>Copyright: ${copyright}</div>
          <div class='media'>Media_type: ${source[i].media_type}</div>
          <div class='service'>Service_version: ${source[i].service_version}</div>
         <div class='content'>Explanation: ${content}
         ......
         </div>
         <button class='details'>Show details</button><br>
        <button class='likebutton'>Like</button>  
         <button class='dislikebutton'>Dislike</button>`

    let border = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pho')];
    let img = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    let likebutton = document.querySelectorAll('.likebutton')
    let dislikebutton = document.querySelectorAll('.dislikebutton')
    let details = document.querySelectorAll('.details')
    gallery = [...document.querySelectorAll('.gallery')]
    let explanation = document.querySelectorAll('.content')
    let all = document.querySelectorAll('.allcontent')
    let hr = document.querySelectorAll('hr')
    let mediainfo = document.querySelectorAll('.media')
    let serviceinfo = document.querySelectorAll('.service')
    let alltitle = document.querySelectorAll('.title')
    for (let y in border) {
      function check() {
        if (liked.includes(source[y])) liked.splice(liked.indexOf(source[y]), 1)
        
        if (disliked.includes(source[y])) disliked.splice(disliked.indexOf(source[y]), 1)
      }
        
      border[y].addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=> img[y].style.transform = 'scale(1.3)')
      border[y].addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=> img[y].style.transform = 'scale(1)')

    
      img[y].onerror = function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
        let error = document.createElement('div')
        error.innerHTML = "We are sorry but at this time we are unable to load <i>this image</i> or doesn't support <i>this type of media</i>"
        error.className = 'error'
        border[y].appendChild(error)
      }
      likebutton[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.textContent === 'Like') {
          this.classList.add('clicked')
          this.textContent = "Liked"
          dislikebutton[y].classList.remove('clicked')
          dislikebutton[y].textContent = "Dislike"
          check()
          liked.push(source[y])
        } else {
          this.classList.remove('clicked')
          this.textContent = "Like"
            check()
        }
      })
      dislikebutton[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.textContent === 'Dislike') {
          this.classList.add('clicked')
          this.textContent = 'Disliked'
          likebutton[y].classList.remove('clicked')
          likebutton[y].textContent = "Like"
          check()
          disliked.push(source[y])
        } else {
            this.textContent = 'Dislike'
            this.classList.remove('clicked')
            check()
         }
      })

      details[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.textContent === 'Show details') {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
          alltitle[y].style.fontSize = '40px'
          mediainfo[y].style.display = 'revert'
          serviceinfo[y].style.display = 'revert'
          gallery[y].classList.toggle('more')
          alltitle[y].style.fontSize = '30px'
          explanation[y].textContent = "Explanation: " + source[i].explanation
          gallery[y].style.opacity = 1;
          img[y].classList.toggle('new')
          border[y].classList.toggle('new')
          hr[y].classList.toggle('hr')
          all[y].classList.toggle('all')
          gallery.forEach(item =>{ if(item !== gallery[y])  item.style.opacity = 0.3})

          removebutton = document.createElement('button')
          removebutton.className = 'remove'
          removebutton.textContent = "X"
         this.innerHTML = '<b><i>Hide details</i></b>'
          this.classList.toggle('newdetails')
          gallery[y].appendChild(removebutton)
          document.querySelectorAll(".allmore").forEach(item =>item.style.opacity = 0.3)

          removebutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alltitle[y].style.fontSize = '18px'
            mediainfo[y].style.display = 'none'
            serviceinfo[y].style.display = 'none'
            img[y].classList.toggle('new') 
            details[y].classList.toggle('newdetails')
            border[y].classList.toggle('new')
            gallery[y].classList.toggle('more')
            all[y].classList.toggle('all')
            explanation[y].textContent = "Explanation: " + source[i].explanation.split(' ').slice(0, 20).join(' ')
            details[y].textContent = 'Show details'
            gallery.forEach(item => item.style.opacity = 1)
            document.querySelectorAll(".allmore").forEach(item => item.style.opacity = 1)
            removebutton.remove()
          })
        } else removebutton.click()
      })
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", ()=> send(28))
```

```css
:root {
  --wid: 325px;
  --hei: 275px;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#grid{
   display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}
@keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.load,
.load:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

.load {
  margin: 60px auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
  border-top: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-right: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-left: 1.1em solid grey;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
}


.effect:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 182, 193, 0.9);
  color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
}
.orin {
  width: calc(var(--wid) - 10px);
  height: var(--hei);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.hr {
  text-align: center;
  width: 92.5%;
}

.likebutton,
.dislikebutton {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.6);
}

.likebutton{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--wid) + 230px);
  left: 20px;

}
.dislikebutton{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--wid) + 230px);
  right: 20px;

}

.pho {
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(var(--wid) - 10px);
  height: var(--hei);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.gallery {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  width: var(--wid);
  /*space between + in calc()*/
  height: calc(var(--hei) + 300px);
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 2px 6px 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
.details {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}
.newdetails {
  color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.9);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.details:hover {
  color: #0000EE;
}
.likebutton:hover,
.dislikebutton:hover {
  color: grey;
}
.media,
.service {
  display: none;
}
.fullheart {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: red;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px red);
}
.remove {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 98%;
  top: -168%;
  border: none;
  color: grey;
  background: transparent;
}
.remove:hover {
  border: 1.75px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.more {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 30px 90px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  z-index: 10;
}
.all {
  position: relative;
  width: 45vw;
  height: 60vh;
  left: 50%;
  top: -98%;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.clicked {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.new {
  width: 43vw;
  height: 90vh;
}
.allmore {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.morebutton {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
}
.history {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
}
.home {
  position: relative;
  left: 5%
}
.allmore:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.error {
position: relative;
top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"><div class="load"></div></div>
```

The code works pretty well and nothing wrong with the cod, but several problems I faced and want to improve:

1. I make an `details` button which execute to give several html elements new styles, just like creating a new modules to the elements. I use `classList.toggle()` to switch between them, but it is too massy and need to write a lot of codes to do that. Is there a better and easier way to do this since I always face this problem?
   (From Javascript, line 108-119, 130-138)
2. I use a combination of template literal and `for` loop to create lots of html tag and assign the `EventListener` to them use loop. I am just wondering is this the best way to do that? Could I shorten the code?
3. Are there anything else I should improve to create clearer code?

Thanks for any responds!

*For now, I post the question, the sever is responding with 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR), but I believe it is not the problem about client-side and not my code problem:)